# Is there a function to find the position of a sprite in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I was trying to get the point where to sprite collide so I went to colliderect, but that wasn't working. I am trying to find the function on which you can get the position of a sprite so that I can manually create a rectangle around it.

Answer (score 0):

A [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) has no position. A *Surface* is `blit` at a position on the screen.   [`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position.  The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the center of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `center`. These keyword argument are applied to the attributes of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before it is returned (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for a full list of the keyword arguments).

A [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) encapsulates an [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object and an [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object. It should have and an `image` and a `rect` attribute. `image` stores the sprite and `rect` stores the position and size of the sprite.